# Make one row from multiple in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to create one row from multiple in xslt table.
Like this :

```
 |Table name|Category| Id     |
 |----------+--------+--------|
 | Object 1 | Rooms  | 407843 |
```

But now my xslt template inputs:

```
 |Table name|Category| Id     |
 |----------+--------+--------|
 | Object 1 |        |        |
 |          | Rooms  |        |
 |          |        | 407843 |
```

xml document looks like:

```
<Object>
    <Property>
      <Property property="Table name">Object 1</Property>
      <Property property="Category">Rooms</Property>
      <Property property="Id">407843</Property>
    </Property>
</Object>
```

The problem is that I can't modify xml file, so it's structure will be the same as above.

And xslt file like this:

```
<tr>        
      <td>
       <xsl:for-each select=".">
          <xsl:choose>                
            <xsl:when test="contains(@property, 'Table name')">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </td>

      <td>
       <xsl:for-each select=".">
          <xsl:choose>                
            <xsl:when test="contains(@property, 'Category')">
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </td>

      <td>
       <xsl:for-each select=".">
          <xsl:choose>                
            <xsl:when test="contains(@property, 'Id')">
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are there multiple objects in your input? If yes, do they all have the same properties, in the same order?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple objects and they have the same properties, but sometimes order is not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there are multiple objects and they have the same properties, but
>   sometimes order is not the same.

Let's have this example input:

**XML**

```
<Objects>
    <Object>
        <Property>
            <Property property="Table name">Table 1</Property>
            <Property property="Category">Cat 1</Property>
            <Property property="Id">001</Property>
        </Property>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Property>
            <Property property="Category">Cat 2</Property>
            <Property property="Id">002</Property>
            <Property property="Table name">Table 2</Property>
        </Property>
    </Object>
</Objects>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Objects">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Table</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Id</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="Object/Property">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Property[@property='Table name']"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Property[@property='Category']"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Property[@property='Id']"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result (rendered)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the corresponding column value using XPath predicates, for example :

```
<xsl:template match="Object">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Name</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Id</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Property"/>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Property">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Property[@property='Table name']"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Property[@property='Category']"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Property[@property='Id']"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```